# Got a .dat file with information about shares. Must create a module that calculates average market price

Tags: python, list, file

Okay so I have 4 .dat files of the following format:

```
Purchase Date     Purchase Price     Shares     Symbol

25 Jan 2014           63.70            40         FB

25 Jan 2014           64.04            40         FB

25 Jan 2014           63.97            175        FB

25 Jan 2014           63.72            80         FB
```

The important thing to note is that each column (Purchase Date, Purchase Price, Shares, Symbol) are separated by a tab character (\t). Also "25 Jan 2014" are only separated by commas. Then there's the tab separation again for the price of the share because it's in the next column, and so on. Also apparently there are empty rows.

I must create a module that reads the file I'll put in it (This file was 1 example of 4 files formatted in the same way but different number of prices and share counts) and calculates the average market price of that share (Price x Shares / Total Number of Shares)

So basically the question is how do I point python to the information I want. :/

The only thing I came up with so far is

```
def averagePricePerShare(x):

   """Calculates average market price"""

    sharesdata_file=(open(x,"r")) #opens file
    sharesdata_str=sharesdata_file.read() #reads contents of file into a string
    marketavgprice=(price*shares)/totalshares
```

But of course in the last line none of those variables are defined anywhere yet, because I simlpy don't know how to get to them. Surely I have to make use of the .find() function somehow , I don't really know. Any help would be greatly appreciated. This was my last resort and I've been trying to come up with something on my own before asking for help on a forum. Maybe I'm just stuck because I was working on this assignment for the past 8 hours (pretty big assignment, this is one of the final parts)

EDIT: My bad. It looks like the starting point would be to use the .split() function to split all that text where there's empty lines and then where there's tab spaces? .split('\n') and .split('\t') or something. Or maybe get rid of the empty lines, then work on each line separately and split the lines at .split('\t') so i'll have purchase price at .split('\t')[1] and shares at .split('\t')[2] for each line? If it's something like this how exactly do I do that?

EDIT 2: I have to do it without using a built-in function. Manually. I found out how:

```
first_useful_line=sharesdata_str.split('\n')[2]
```

and so on. So now I guess I will split that line into its columns like this

```
firstlineprice=first_useful_line.split('\t')[1]
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `csv` module to read your data, specifying `delimiter="\t"`:

```
import csv

with open("myfile.dat", "rb") as inf:                # if Python 2.x
# with open("myfile.dat", "r", newline="") as inf:     # if Python 3.x
    incsv = csv.reader(inf, delimiter="\t")

    # skip header row
    next(incsv, None)   

    # read data
    for row in incsv:
        # now do something with row!
```